# Cannot connect to server: user already online

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking

When I try join a server it says "you are already connected to this server".

I have tried connecting a few time but the same thing comes up.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is generally caused by server lag, especially if the server is about to or is in the process of backing up or restarting. If you try again in a few minutes, you should be able to reconnect.

If not, try connecting to another server. If it displays the same thing, you may want to change your Minecraft password, as someone else may have gained access to your account, or you have a token error. Just restart your client and try again.

Answer (score -3):

I have this problem and this is how can i solve it with CCLEANER clean the PC & the registry if doesn't work uninstall the game with CCLEANER and install again.

This solution works for me in 2 games League of legends & battlefield

Comment: What does that have to do with Minecraft?

Comment: I very much doubt CCleaner would do anything to solve this problem; all it does is remove temporary files and invalid registry entries.